# How to detect PID

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I trying detect PID in my shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run serve-prod &
pid=$(pgrep serve-prod)
echo $pid
```

Then a while

```
echo "waiting for webserver"
while ! nc -z localhost 9000; do
sleep 1 # wait for 1/10 of the second before check again
done
```

Then call a script

```
npm run print-map
```

And finish kill process

```
pkill serve-prod
```

Problem is  process is still runing

Comment: Use `pgrep`, otherwise you'll include the PID of the `grep` process as well.

Comment: Hmm but i cannot kill now with command

kill -9 $pid ?

Comment: Use `pkill`, it combines the grep and kill into one command.

Comment: Ok so i tried `pkill $(pgrep $pid)` so im confused now.

Comment: `pkill serve-prod`

Comment: `pid=$(pgrep serve-prod)`

Comment: Did you  read the man page so you'd understand how they're used?

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, it's unreadable. Edit the question.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be doing any of this at all on a modern system. Use your operating system's service manager -- it knows the PID of every service it runs.

Comment: So if you're on a Linux distro that uses systemd, define `serve-prod.service`, so you can run `systemctl start serve-prod`, `systemctl stop serve-prod`, etc.

Comment: (by contrast, if you're on MacOS, its service manager is launchd, so you'd be building a .plist instead of a .service file and using `launchctl` instead of `systemctl` to start/stop/check status/etc, but it's all the same idea).

Comment: ...and using the system service manager will let you do things like define whether you want the service to start on boot, what other services need to be started first, how and when you want it to be restarted on failures, etc etc.

Comment: ...better UNIX shops were already using process supervision in the early 2000s -- systemd didn't exist (and it's problematic anyhow), but we had DJB's daemontools, smarden.org's runit, etc; these days, when no major distro ships SysV init anymore, there's really no excuse for doing things like we were still in the 70s/80s/90s. (And really, if you go back far enough, folks used to use `inittab` for process supervision with automatic startup and restarting; the world went backwards when folks stopped using that in favor of having fire-and-forget `rc` scripts w/ start/stop/restart commands).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for detect PID:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
pid=0
npm run serve-prod &
pid=$!
echo $pid
```